# Relationship between Isolation Level and Locks

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am trying to understand the relationship between Isolation Levels (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173763.aspx) and locks (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  I read a similar question on here and the answerer said

"Locks are implementation details.  If you have a transaction that contains a SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
```

You only have to worry about what data you will see from SomeTable"

However, if we do not have to worry about them then why do we have: Table Hints (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).  Do we have to think about locks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, locks are partly an implementation detail. They are used (in SQL Server) to give you the guarantees that the isolation levels give you according to the standard. For example, `SERIALIZABLE` gives you as-if single-threaded access to the database. This is done by S-locking all data you have read in order to freeze it.

Locks are not purely a detail because the very details of a locking scheme leak out. They are detectable. Also, you can control locks using hints to create behavior that is not specified in the standard. Usually, one would do that to obtain stronger guarantees than before.

Comment: Is it fair to say that as a developer you would not really think about locks most the time? You would only concentrate on choosing the correct isolation level for the requirement?

Comment: Some of the isolation levels are very intuitive. Some are not. Think as high-level as possible. So yes, the isolation level is the right level most of the time.; I like to recognize patterns. For example read-only transactions are always best at SNAPSHOT. Low-volume transactions are usually best left at SERIALIZABLE so that you don't have to think about correctness.; Concurrency correctness is not all or nothing. Accounting systems need more thought than, say, a blog. Sometimes you can get away with simply disregarding concurrency and not caring about very small data corruption probabilities.

Comment: Thanks +1.  When you say high level and low level are you referring to the type of system e.g. accounting system or the type of requirement e.g. Bookkeeping in an accounting system.

Comment: I was referring to the concurrency strategy. For example the strategy to make read-only trans SNAPSHOT is a very high-level way of making these kinds of transactions 100% safe and remove 100% of potential blocking issues. Applying an UPDLOCK hint, though, is a very low-level technique that is rarely a good choice.; This advice is less about correctness but about saving dev time and having less bugs.

Comment: Finally, is the default lock type for each isolation type documented somewhere.  I cannot find it.  I believe I know the default in for each type but it would be good to see it in black and white.

Comment: I found the documentation to be lacking. It is not just a default type. The levels vary by what is locked and for how long (are the locks held to the end of the transaction?). Also SERIALIZABLE takes range locks while the other levels do not (where possible). If you really want to know what is going on run simple statements with SQL Profiler attached.; Lots of stuff: http://www.brentozar.com/isolation-levels-sql-server/